# createdAt cannot be an array or an object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Can someone help me I'm having problems inserting a record in the database with sequelize, created_at and updated_at are automatically filled and this is with this error:

```
"name": "SequelizeValidationError",
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "createdAt cannot be an array or an object",
        "type": "string violation",
        "path": "createdAt",
        "value": "2020-05-28T22:04:45.023Z",
        "origin": "CORE",
        "instance": {
            "id": null,
            "placeId": "1",
            "userId": 3,
            "name": "Alex Santos",
            "email": "customer@gmail.com",
            "documento": "00000000000",
            "phone": "(37)98596-9869",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-28T22:04:45.023Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-28T22:04:45.023Z"
        },
        "validatorKey": "not_a_string",
        "validatorName": null,
        "validatorArgs": []
    },
    {
        "message": "customer.updateAt cannot be null",
        "type": "notNull Violation",
        "path": "updateAt",
        "value": null,
        "origin": "CORE",
        "instance": {
            "id": null,
            "placeId": "1",
            "userId": 3,
            "name": "Alex Santos",
            "email": "customer@gmail.com",
            "documento": "031.682.546-81",
            "phone": "(37)98596-9869",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-28T22:04:45.023Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-28T22:04:45.023Z"
        },
        "validatorKey": "is_null",
        "validatorName": null,
        "validatorArgs": []
    }
]
```

}

Can someone provide any suggestions to help? I think in customer.js create() function is having some sort of miss from my side.

Could there be any other solution?

customer.js

```
   /* jshint indent: 1 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('customer', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            field: 'id'
        },
        placeId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'places',
                key: 'id'
            },
            field: 'place_id'
        },
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'users',
                key: 'id'
            },
            field: 'user_id'
        },
        customerId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'customer_id'
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'name'
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'email'
        },
        documento: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(16),
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '',
            field: 'documento'
        },
        phone: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(12),
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'phone'
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'created_at'
        },
        updateAt: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'update_at'
        }

    }, {
        tableName: 'customer'
    });
};
```

CustomerController.js

```
const Customers = require('./../models/custumers')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../../bin/database');
const Customer = new Customers(db, Sequelize);
exports.create = async(req, res) => {
    decodeToken = await jwt.decodeToken(req.headers['x-access-token'])
    let userId = decodeToken.id
    console.log(new Date())
    let { placeId, customerId, name, email, documento, phone } = req.body
    Customer.create({
            placeId,
            userId,
            customerId,
            name,
            email,
            documento,
            phone
        })
        .then((Customer) => {
            return res.status(200).send({ Customer: Customer })
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(423).send(err);
        });
}
```

Comment: can you set timestamps: true after tableName property?

Comment: without effect, the error continues.

Comment: Your customer.js file has `updateAt:`. I think that should be `updatedAt:`.

Comment: Resolved or null field problem, but the error still continues "createdAt cannot be an array or an object"  and "updatedAt cannot be an array or an object"

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what is wrong. You defined the `createdAt` column as a String but it would appear that you are sending an object (very likely of type Date). The value of type Date is not a String, and so Sequelize is warning you with information like `"validatorKey": "not_a_string"` and `"type": "string violation"`.

I don't know why you elected to store a timestamp as a String, but part of the fix is to change the column to type Date.

You also mentioned that the column value is filled automatically, but I don't see anywhere where that would take place. Unless you are explicitly setting a default value for the column and then not providing a value when committing the session, these columns will not be automatically filled.

The short answer is, change the column type to DATE and make sure to set a timestamp on the value before committing to the db.